# Ruby regex syntax for "not matching one of the following"

Tags: ruby, regex

Nice simple regex syntax question for you.

I have a block of text and i want to find instances of `href="` or `href='` which are NOT followed by either `[` or `http://`

I can get "not followed by `[`" with

`record.body =~ /href=['"](?!\[)/`

and i can get "not followed by `http://`" with

`record.body =~ /href=['"](?!http\:\/\/)/`

But i can't quite work out how to combine the two.

Just to be clear:  i want to find bad strings like this

```
`href="www.foo.com"`
```

but i'm ok with (ie don't want to find) strings like this

```
`href="http://www.foo.com"`
`href="[registration_url]"`
```

Comment: You seem to have typo'd `http="` as `http=\"`. Is that correct, or do you want to find `\"`?

Comment: It's not a typo as such, it's how the " shows up when you inspect the string.  But this might be confusing, i'll amend the question, thanks.

Comment: disagree with the downvote btw, this relates to a fairly unintuitive aspect of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the both by using the alternation operator.

```
href=['"](?!http\:\/\/|\[)
```

For more specific, it would be.

```
href=(['"])(?!http\:\/\/|\[)(?:(?!\1).)*\1
```

This would handle both single quoted or double quoted string in the `href` part. And this won't match the strings like `href='foo.com"` or `href="foo.com'` (*unmatched quotes*)

`(['"])` would capture double quote or single quote. `(?!http\:\/\/|\[)` and the matched quote won't be followed by `http://` or `[`, if yes, then it moves on to the next pattern. `(?:(?!\1).)*` matches any character but not of the captured character, zero or more times. `\1` followed by the captured character.

[DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/Nxd3jORu5g)

Comment: thanks - would you mind explaining what the `(?:(?!\1).)*\1`  at the end is for? The first one seems to work as is.

Comment: but the first one matches `href="` substring only. If you want to match the whole href part then use the second one.

Comment: ah, i see:  i just need to find instances of where it occurs, but the second one would be useful if i actually wanted to test what the href was set to, for example, so thanks for both.

Answer (score 1):

Use [alternative list](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) with pipe `|` symbol to combine the look-ahead conditions:

```
(?!http\:\/\/|\[)
```

So, to match the hrefs, you can use the following regex:

```
href=\"((?!http\:\/\/|\[)[^\"]+?)\"
```

See [demo on Rubular.com](http://rubular.com/r/bYflEUrnuN).